# Automated Debugging of failed API test cases

Tags: testing, automated-tests

Our application has 35 web servers and around 100 different APIs being executed on it.

These APIs internally calls each other and execute independently as well.
We have automated test cases of around 30 APIs but some of our tests fail because the other APIs fail on which the API under test depends.

So how can we know through our automated test cases the reason for each test failure?

**Example Scenario:**

We have a test case to validate the API to fetch the User's Bank account balance.

Now we hit this API through rest Assured and tries to assert the expected output. This request goes first to the ledger server which further internally hits auth server to validate the request authenticity, then hits, then hits a counter server to log fetchBalance request, then hits several other servers to get the correct balance of the user and then responds to our request.

But the problem is that this may break at any instance and if it breaks, the ledger server returns always same error string- "Something failed underhood". Now debugging becomes a challenge. We have to go to each server and have to search for the logs to know the actual cause.

I want to write a solution which can trace complete lifecycle of this request and can report where it actually failed.

Comment: Can you share an example of a API test? What is a reason of test failures? Do you get an unexpected response code?

Comment: Example added to the description. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you should be aware of the most common failure reasons. And then you can implement the strategy bases on the failure reasons.

Example: If you have send one request to the server that API may have some security validations and some processing steps and integration with different components.
If you can identify some failure points and can implement checkpoints against that.

1. Request failed at Security validation. You have possible error codes for that then write logic according to that
2. You have a failure at the processing step there could be a possible reason
3. If there is a failure at the integration point then there must be some error codes also. You can implement logic around them

Answer (score 0):

Validate the state of data before each interaction with server. For example

```
assert expression1 : expression2
```

Where `expression2` will be executed if `expression1` fails. (This is a Groovy example, but you can modify this as needed.)

An example `expression2` message could be something like: "Failure occured when trying to send 'so-and-so' request!".